# What is Python's equivalent of Java's standard for-loop?

Tags: java, python, loops, for-loop, translate

I'm writing a simple algorithm to check the primality of an integer and I'm having a problem translating this Java code into Python:

```java
for (int i = 3; i < Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) {
    if (n % i == 0)
        return false;
}
```

So, I've been trying to use this, but I'm obviously skipping the division by 3:

```py
i = 3
while (i < int(math.sqrt(n))):
    i += 2  # where do I put this?
    if (n % i == 0):
        return False
```

Comment: `for (a; b; c) { _ }` -> `a; while(b) { _; c; }` - barring scoping issues and having to deal with `continue`. The last component of the for-each construct is evalutated *after* each evaluation of the loop body.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html in reference to wanting to translate java (or other languages) to python - don't forget to be pythonic!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The only `for`-loop in Python is technically a "for-each", so you can use something like

```py
for i in xrange(3, int(math.sqrt(n)), 2):  # use 'range' in Python 3
    if n % i == 0:
        return False
```

Of course, Python can do better than that:

```py
all(n % i for i in xrange(3, int(math.sqrt(n)), 2))
```

would be equivalent as well (assuming there's a `return true` at the end of that Java loop). Indeed, the latter would be considered the *Pythonic* way to approach it.

---

**Reference:**

- [`for` Statements](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)
- [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange)
- [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

Comment: Python has while loops… Or am I misinterpreting part of your answer?

Comment: @mipadi I think he meant Python doesn't have the C-like `for` loop that merges an initializer, stop condition, and step statement. That is: the only `for` in Python is a `foreach`.

Comment: Indeed, I clarified that statement.

Answer (score 4):

A direct translation would be:

```
for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)), 2):
    if n % i == 0:
        return False
```

Answer (score 3):

In a Java for loop, the step (the `i += 2` part in your example) occurs at the end of the loop, just before it repeats. Translated to a while, your for loop would be equivalent to:

```
int i = 3;
while (i < Math.sqrt(n)) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    i += 2;
}
```

Which in Python is similar:

```
i = 3
while i < math.sqrt(n):
    if n % i == 0:
        return False
    i += 2
```

However, you can make this more "Pythonic" and easier to read by using Python's [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) function, which allows you to specify a `step` parameter:

```
for i in xrange(3, math.sqrt(n), 2):
    if n % i == 0:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a basic Python `for i in range` loop:

```
for i in range(3, math.round(math.sqrt(x)), 2):
    if (n % i == 0):
        return false
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this answer from an automatic translation by AgileUML:

```
def op(self, n) :
  result = False
  i = 0
  i = 3
  while i < math.sqrt(n) :
    if n % i == 0 :
      return False
    else :
      pass
    i = (i + 2)
  return True
```

It seems to be semantically correct?