# How to alter FOR loop checking condition on range values in PYTHON?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, for-loop, data-structures

Is there a way to use FOR loop in python such that checking conditions on range values can be altered.
**Basically convert this code into python using FOR loop**(not using while loop or if-break).

```
for(int i = 1;i*i<=n;++i)
   { 
     #code statements
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does filter work for you?

```
n = 100
for i in filter(lambda x: x**2 <= n, range(1, n)):
    print(i, i**2)
```

Comment: Wow this is great, i didn't knew about filter(). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could check the highest value of `i` beforehand by taking the square root of `n`.

```
n = 10
for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1):
    print(i, i**2)

1 1
2 4
3 9
```

Comment: Okay this is one way, but is there like a way that we can change condition on i instead of n. Thanks btw. :)

Comment: No, pythons for loop is basically a for-each, it doesn't have a for loop like the ones in java for example. So then you'd have to fall back to a while loop with if and break. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415198/what-is-pythons-equivalent-of-javas-standard-for-loop

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks.